# SAS: Concatenating variables from multiple data sets

Tags: sql, join, dataset, concatenation, sas

I'm a somewhat new user to SAS and a problem that has recently arisen is as follows:

I currently have two data sets: Year_1 & Year_2.

Examples:

**Year_1**

```
*Name.....Q1 ..... Q2.....Q3.....Q4*
Andrew....1 ........0.........1........0
Anson......1..........1..........0........1
```

**Year_2**

```
*Name.....Q1 ..... Q2.....Q3.....Q4*
Andrew....1 .........1.........0.........0
Anson......0..........1..........0........1
```

What I am attempting to do is join the following tables on *Name* (unique identifier) while concatenating the values, particularly Q1-Q4, to produce:

**Both_Years**

```
*Name.....Q1 ..... Q2.....Q3.....Q4*
Andrew....11 ......01........10.....00
Anson......10.......11.......00.......11
```

Since Andrew received 1 for Q1 Year_1 and a 1 for Q1 Year_2, the final result would be 11, and so on. I have attempting looking at macros & arrays, however, I have yet to find a solution and any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Also, please forgive my lack of experience with forum-writing and any lack of proper formatting. Hopefully it is still easily undertsood.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get both lines accessible at once.  You can do that one of two ways in the datastep; merging or setting the datasets together.  In this case merging is a little tricky because you have same-named variables; you'd have to `rename` them to something different or they'll just overwrite.

For example:

```
data  merged;
merge year_1(rename=(q1=q1y1 q2=q2y1 q3=q3y1 q4=q4y1) in=y1) 
      year_2(rename=(q1=q1y2 q2=q2y2 q3=q3y2 q4=q4y2) in=y2);
by name;
if y1 and y2; *or some other logic - this would include only records found in both years 
*remove the above line if all combinations of matches or non-matches are okay;
q1=cats(of q1:);
q2=cats(of q2:);
q3=cats(of q3:);
q4=cats(of q4:);
run;
```

`cats` concatenates, and `of` allows space-delimited list of variables; `:` is wildcard, so all things starting with q1.

You could also use set:

```
data set_together;
set year_1 year_2;
by name;
retain q1_c q2_c q3_c q4_c; *save the value from each iteration;
if first.name then do; *for a new name, clear out the markers;
call missing(of q1_c q2_c q3_c q4_c); *clear them out;
end;
q1_c = cats(q1_c,q1);
q2_c = cats(q1_c,q1);
q3_c = cats(q1_c,q1);
q4_c = cats(q1_c,q1);
if last.name then output; *keep only last row for each name;
run;
```

You could of course use RENAMES here also if you wanted to keep `q1` style names in the final file.

Both require the datasets to be sorted by `name`.

You also could use PROC SQL to do it:

```
proc sql;
create table want as select y1.name, cats(year1.q1,year2.q1) as q1, cats(year1.q2,year2.q2) as q2, cats(year1.q3,year2.q3) as q3, cats(year1.q4,year2.q4) as q4
from year_1 y1, year_2 y2
where y1.name=y2.name;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to merge the datasets to get everything you need in one place, then use a concatenation function to get everything into one variable. Concatenation will produce a character string, so if you need the answers to remain numeric, you will need to convert them back into numbers after the concatenation. Here's some code that should do the trick:

```
proc sort data = year_1;
    by name;
run;

proc sort data = year_2;
    by name;
run;

data both_years;
    merge year_1 (rename = (Q1=Q1_1 Q2=Q2_1 Q3=Q3_1 Q4=Q4_1))
          year_2 (rename = (Q1=Q1_2 Q2=Q2_2 Q3=Q3_2 Q4=Q4_2));
    by name;
    format Q1-Q4 $20.;
    Q1 = cat(Q1_1,Q1_2);
    Q2 = cat(Q2_1,Q2_2);
    Q3 = cat(Q3_1,Q3_2);
    Q4 = cat(Q4_1,Q4_2);

    keep name Q1-Q4;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `proc sql`.  Assuming you have the same list of names in both tables:

```
proc sql;
    select t1.name,
           (t1.Q1||t2.Q1) as Q1,
           (t1.Q2||t2.Q2) as Q2,
           (t1.Q3||t2.Q3) as Q3,
           (t1.Q4||t2.Q4) as Q4
    from table1 t1 join
         table2 t2
         on t1.name = t2.name;
```

If the list of names are different, then you might want a `left join`, `right join`, or `full join`.